# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, sqlite

one of my A Level students are trying to get their code to work in Python 3 but it keeps coming up with the error message: "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied". The code is as follows:

```
import sqlite3

def query(sql,data):
    with sqlite3.connect("DogBreeds.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql,data)
        db.commit()

def insert_dog_breed_data(records):
    sql = "insert into DogBreed(Breed, Description, Previous_Litters) values (?,?,?)"
    for record in records:
        query(sql,record)

def insert_dog_data(records):
    sql = "insert into Dogs (Name, Date of Birth, Gender, DogBreedID) values (?,?,?,?)"
    for record in records:
        query(sql,record)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dog_breeds = [("Shih Tzu",),("Jack Russell",),("Great Dane",),("Husky"("Cavalier King Charles Spaniel",),("Pug")]
    insert_dog_breed_data(dog_breeds)
    dogs = [("Steve", "10/08/2006", "Male",1),("John","08/05/2017", "Male",2),("Ellen", "25/12/2013","Female",3),("Betty", "13/01/2000", "Female",4),("Charlie", "30/03/2000", "Female",5),("Fred", "04/05/2000", "Male",5)]
    insert_dog_data(dogs)
```

and the full error message is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "G:\Dog Breeder Scenario - Python\Insert data 2.py", line 21, in <module>
> insert_dog_breed_data(dog_breeds)   File "G:\Dog Breeder Scenario - Python\Insert data 2.py", line 12, in insert_dog_breed_data
> query(sql,record)   File "G:\Dog Breeder Scenario - Python\Insert data 2.py", line 6, in query
> cursor.execute(sql,data)
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied.
> ```

As a guide they are following the tutorial from Python School website - Task 4 from  https://pythonschool.net/databases/inserting-data/

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: can you please indent your code properly

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a list of single-item tuples into `insert_dog_breed_data` - containing the breed name only - but the SQL query is expecting three items - name, description, previous_litters.

Note, one of the most useful skills a new programmer can learn is how to read error messages. All the information they - and you - needed to solve this themselves was presented in that message.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman and Ev. Kounis, I will get them to try this out and let you know how they get on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (as @DanielRoseman explained) that `sqlite` expects tuples containing **3** items each (*Breed*, *Description*, *Previous_Litters*) but the ones you are providing only contain one since:

```
dog_breeds = [("Shih Tzu",),("Jack Russell",),("Great Dane",),("Husky"("Cavalier King Charles Spaniel",),("Pug")])
```

One solution would be to modify your `dog_breeds` tuples before passing it on to the `insert_dog_breed_data` function as follows:

```
dog_breeds = [(x,) + ('', '') for x in dog_breeds]
```

Assuming you do not have the info on the *Description* and *Previous_Litters* available.

which will create tuples like this one: `("Shih Tzu", '', '')`

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman and Ev. Kounis, I will get them to try this out and let you know how they get on.